Show that the equation $x^4 - x^3 - 6x^2 - 2x + 9 = 0$ cannot have negative roots.
I see that the equation has two sign changes, so it can have two positive roots and $f(-x)$ also has two sign changes, so it can have two negative roots. Essentially it can have two positive roots, two negative roots or two complex roots.
Now I apply Vieta's relations, and find that $\sum\alpha = 1, \sum\alpha_i\alpha_j = -6, \sum\alpha_i\alpha_j\alpha_k = 2, \alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_3\alpha_4 = 9$.
I tried various ways to deduce that there cannot be two negative roots using these relations, but I cannot find it.

How do I prove that? I see that when $0<x<1$ then 9 will dominate and also see that when $x < -2$ then also it is true. But I do not know how to prove it between $-1$ and $-2$.

If $x < 0$ then $-6x^2$ won't be positive.

For a general quartic equation, it is possible to convert into quadratic form and study https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function.

It just dawned upon me that we can rewrite the equation as $(x^2 - 3)^2 - x^3 - 2x$ which is greater than $0$ for negative $x$.
